# How to refresh StatefulWidget after called Navigator.pushNamed()

Tags: flutter, dart

### What I'm doing

There are two pages: profile and login page.

The profile page is shown first, but when user not already logged in, profile page doesn't show profile and show login button.

Profile code

```
bool loggedin = false;      // If user already logged in return true


class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const Profile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Profile createState() => _Profile();
}

class _Profile extends State<Profile> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loggedin
        ? Column(children: [  //.... some user information
                     ])
        : needLogin(context);
  }
}

Widget needLogin(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
            TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/login");
            },
            child: const Text(
              "Login",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            )),
      );
}
```

Loggin page

```
// The code to login is omitted. if login succeeded do loggedin = true; in setState()

var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if (user != null) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  setState(() {
    loggedin = true;
  });
}

// Then back to profile page automatically
```

### Problem

I did `loggedin = true;` in `setState()` but profile page still shows login button of `needLogin()`.

The reason I wrote `needLogin()` outside of `StatefulWidget` is to reuse it with other `StatefulWidget`.

### Question

How can I update previous page when call `setState()` in the page which generated by `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the `needLogin` method and also pass the success state/bool back through the Navigator:

Profile Code

```
 class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const Profile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Profile createState() => _Profile();
}

class _Profile extends State<Profile> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loggedin
        ? Column(children: [  //.... some user information
                     ])
        : needLogin(context, () => setState(() {loggedIn = true}));
  }
}


 Widget needLogin(BuildContext context, void Function() setStateFunction) {
    return Center(
      child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.of(context)
                .pushNamed("/login")
                .then((result) {
              if (result as bool) {
                setStateFunction.call();
              }
            });
          },
          child: const Text(
            "Login",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Login page

```
var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if (user != null) {
   Navigator.pop(context, true);
}
```

Comment: It works! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't

> loggedin

outside of the widget.

Use it within:

> class _Profile extends State {

Also, you may want to look into some State Management techniques like Provider with Change Notifier for instance. It's quite easy to use and will do exactly what you need.

UI shouldn't contain the business logic and should be rendered based on some sort of controller. This makes code more consistent, readable and testable.